# MySQL Multiple Left Joins - One Column Is Incorrect

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL database, I have 4 tables: `jtbl_users`, `wat_team`, `wat_league`, `wat_team_member`. I'm needing to run a query that pulls a list of team members that show what team they are on and the `league_code` that the team is assigned to. A team member can be assigned to multiple teams.

I've been unable to match the `league_code` with each team, if a team member is on multiple teams it will only pull the `league_code` that the most recent team the team member has joined.

I have to pull from the `wat_team_member` table, that does not contain the `league_id`, the `league_id' is in the`wat_team` table.

```
`jtbl_users`
=============
id | name
1012 | James
1067 | Steve
1133 | Lisa

`wat_league`
=============
id | league_name | code
793 | Southeast County | x1234fr
678 | North County | df987gt

`wat_team`
=============
id | team_name | league_id | league_code
36 | Jawhawks | 793 | x1234fr
50 | Clippers | 678 | df987gt
62 | Bears | 793 | x1234fr

`wat_team_member`
=============
id | user_id | team_id
1 | 1012 | 36
2 | 1067 | 36
3 | 1067 | 50
4 | 1133 | 62

SELECT
jtbl_users.name,
wat_team.team_name,
wat_league.league_code
FROM wat_team_member

LEFT JOIN jtbl_users ON jtbl_users.id = wat_team_member.user_id
LEFT JOIN wat_team ON wat_team.id = wat_team_member.team_id
LEFT JOIN wat_league ON wat_league.id IN (SELECT league_id FROM wat_team WHERE wat_team_member.team_id = wat_team.id)
WHERE jtbl_users.id = 1067
```

returns:

```
name | team_name | league_code
--------------
Steve | Jawhawks | df987gt
Steve | Clippers | df987gt
```

But am needing:

```
name | team_name | league_code
--------------
Steve | Jawhawks | x1234fr
Steve | Clippers | df987gt
```

Comment: If you are using the league_id from wat_team, why not just join to wat_team?

Comment: Thanks Uueerdo, different from the current "LEFT JOIN wat_team" join I have in there?  I've also tried "LEFT JOIN wat_league ON wat_league.id = wat_team.league_id" and it returns the same way as it currently is.  Thanks again.

Comment: Change WHERE to AND

Comment: Hi Strawberry, the "WHERE" in the subquery of the the 3rd LEFT JOIN?  I tried that but it returned a SQL syntax error "near 'AND wat_team_member.team_id'.  Thanks.

Comment: @hominid4 Yeah, I was referring to using the ` ON wat_league.id = wat_team.league_id` condition; that _should_ have given you the league for the team in the result row.  Not that it should matter for this, but are the two 2's in `wat_team_member` a typo?

Comment: @Uueerdo , thanks, I was thinking the same, not sure why it's not giving me the needed return result.  I'm away from my work computer, I'll play around with the query more when I get back.  Ah shoot, yes, sorry, the two 2s is a typo, I've corrected that.  Thanks again.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? The only other thing I can think of is looking into [CHECK TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/check-table.html), and [REPAIR TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/repair-table.html).